# Add a loader div in between body tag and pagewrapper div

Tags: magento2.3

I want to add a div after the body tag. How I update the layout code.

Answer (score 0):

This official docs may help you https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html
Basically you need to add your div in container `after.body.start`